# Unable to send json in ajax to django without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to use `AJAX` with `Django` but without `jQuery`, almost I am successful in doing so but only `urlencoded` data can be sent from AJAX to Django and unable to send data in JSON format, but I am able to get a response from `Django` to `AJAX` in `JSON` format too.

I have tried a lot as you can see comments in these files:

senddata.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Send AJAX data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Send AJAX data by using the button</h2>
    <button id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">SEND</button>


    <script>
        var sendbtn = document.getElementById('btn-submit')
        sendbtn.addEventListener('click', sendBtnHandler)

        function sendBtnHandler() {
            console.log('sendBtn is clicked')

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8000/contact/send', true)
            // xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");


            xhr.onprogress = function () {
                console.log("on progress, wait a while until data is fetched")
            }

            xhr.onload = function () {
                console.log('success')
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }

            let params = `{"name":"mayur90","salary":"12213","age":"23"}`
            let b = 2
            let d = 4 
            // let params = `a=${b}&c=${d}`
            xhr.send(params)
            // xhr.send(b)
            console.log(params)

        }
    </script>





    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

urls.py

```python
from django.urls import path
from ajaxcontact import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('send', views.senddata, name='senddata'),
]
```

views.py

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def senddata(request):
    print(request.method)
    # print(request.GET)
    print('POST requests are', request.POST)
    print(request.POST.get('name'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return JsonResponse('{"name":"a"}', safe=False)
    return render(request, 'senddata.html')
```

Here, I use `@csrf_exempt` to create the POST without the csrf token
I am able to send data in `urlencoded` but unable to send it in `JSON` format

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: why don't you use fetch? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

your urls should match with request url based on main domain. So change your urls.py file to 
`path('/contact/send', views.senddata, name='senddata')`